# Should my credit record show addresses where I never lived?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-report

I have an address on my credit report, where I have never lived, but my ex has.

Now I understand it is fine to have a link to her on the report, but her addresses should presumably feature on her report (traceable through the link to her) rather than directly on mine?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any evidence that this is normal if you've never had any connection to the addresses. But you can get a connection to an address from just having mail redirected to it by Royal Mail.

An unexpected address can be a sign of identity fraud, perhaps in this case by your ex. Obviously only you can judge if that's a reasonable suspicion.

If your finances are now disentangled, you should be able to file a "notice of disassociation" from your ex and see if that makes the address disappear.

You can also just ask directly for the address to be removed. The credit reference agency would then contact the institution(s) that added it to get more information about where it came from.

Source for some of this: https://help.creditexpert.co.uk/help/sv635/Credit_report/linked_addresses

Comment: Credit agencies have been notorious in the past for having incomplete or incorrect data. Once I was shown as living at two addresses I had considered buying, but never actually made an offer on. Notify the credit agency of the error and they will have to correct it. I don't know how quickly it is required in the uk.